# Unable to update binary values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

In my table, I have a field of length 93 and type binary. I retrieve it as array, modify it as array and then insert it. While inserting back to db, I find garbage values. 
Well, this all is because of the string array being updated in place of binary. 
How shall I update it? Using 2.3.5 cakephp and mysql.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We're gonna need to see some code but my guess is that you're not inserting it properly.